# Expectation value of momentum in a particular eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, potential, schroedinger-equation

Suppose a particle is in time independent potential and NOT in any superposition of eigenstates. Then expectation value of position is time independent and expectation value of momentum should always be zero according to Ehrenfest theorem.Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. An eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $H={p^2\over 2m}+V(x)$ being of the form
$$\psi_n(x,t)=\phi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$
the average position
$$\eqalign{
 \langle x(t)\rangle
  &=\int \psi_n^*(x,t)x\psi_n(x,t)dx\cr
  &=\int |\phi_n(x)|^2xdx\cr
 }$$
is indeed time-independent and, as a consequence of Ehrenfest theorem
$${d\over dt}\langle x\rangle={i\over\hbar}\langle [H,x]\rangle
=\langle p\rangle$$
the average moment should vanish
$$\langle p\rangle=0$$